# Read Excel file from a URL using the readxl package

Tags: r, excel, readxl

Consider a file on the internet (like this one (note the s in https) https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/SDTM/SDTM%20Terminology.xls

How can the sheet 2 of the file be read into R?

The following code is approximation of what is desired (but fails)

```
url1<-'https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/SDTM/SDTM%20Terminology.xls'
p1f <- tempfile()
download.file(url1, p1f, mode="wb")
p1<-read_excel(path = p1f, sheet = 2)
```

Comment: per this link even download.file() should not be necessary but I can't make it work. https://github.com/hadley/readxl/pull/77

Comment: I don't think `read_excel` is capable of handling Excel workbook files that do not have a `.xls` extension.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This works for me on Windows:

```
library(readxl)
library(httr)
packageVersion("readxl")
# [1] ‘0.1.1’

GET(url1, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
df <- read_excel(tf, 2L)
str(df)
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 20131 obs. of  8 variables:
# $ Code                        : chr  "C115388" "C115800" "C115801" "C115802" ...
# $ Codelist Code               : chr  NA "C115388" "C115388" "C115388" ...
# $ Codelist Extensible (Yes/No): chr  "No" NA NA NA ...
# $ Codelist Name               : chr  "6 Minute Walk Functional Test Test Code" "6 Minute Walk Functional Test Test Code" "6 Minute Walk Functional Test Test Code" "6 Minute Walk Functional Test Test Code" ...
# $ CDISC Submission Value      : chr  "SIXMW1TC" "SIXMW101" "SIXMW102" "SIXMW103" ...
# $ CDISC Synonym(s)            : chr  "6 Minute Walk Functional Test Test Code" "SIXMW1-Distance at 1 Minute" "SIXMW1-Distance at 2 Minutes" "SIXMW1-Distance at 3 Minutes" ...
# $ CDISC Definition            : chr  "6 Minute Walk Test test code." "6 Minute Walk Test - Distance at 1 minute." "6 Minute Walk Test - Distance at 2 minutes." "6 Minute Walk Test - Distance at 3 minutes." ...
# $ NCI Preferred Term          : chr  "CDISC Functional Test 6MWT Test Code Terminology" "6MWT - Distance at 1 Minute" "6MWT - Distance at 2 Minutes" "6MWT - Distance at 3 Minutes" ...
```

Comment: how silly to forget to try that the extension makes the difference. It does make good sense to require it.

Comment: How delete from R the tempfile?

Comment: @HenryNavarro in R use ```unlink(tf)```

Answer (score 14):

A simpler solution is using the **openxlsx package**. Here is an example, which can be adapted to your needs:

```
library(openxlsx)
df = read.xlsx("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00242/ENB2012_data.xlsx",sheet=1)
```

Answer (score 9):

From [this issue on Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/278) (#278):

> some functionality for supporting more general inputs will be pulled out of readr, at which point readxl can exploit that.

So we should be able to pass urls directly to `read_excel()` in the (hopefully near) future.

Comment: As of August 2020, this issue is still open. Subsequently, `read_excel()` will not yet read `.xls` files directly from the web.

Comment: Still not a feature in 2024. I don't think it's happening.

Answer (score 8):

use `rio` R package. [link](https://github.com/leeper/rio). Here a reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rio)
url <- 'https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/CDISC/SDTM/SDTM%20Terminology.xls'
rio::import(file = url,which = 2) %>% 
  glimpse()
#> 
#> Rows: 30,995
#> Columns: 8
#> $ Code                           <chr> "C141663", "C141706", "C141707"...
#> $ `Codelist Code`                <chr> NA, "C141663", "C141663", "C141...
#> $ `Codelist Extensible (Yes/No)` <chr> "No", NA, NA, NA, "No", NA, NA,...
#> $ `Codelist Name`                <chr> "4 Stair Ascend Functional Test...
#> $ `CDISC Submission Value`       <chr> "A4STR1TC", "A4STR101", "A4STR1...
#> $ `CDISC Synonym(s)`             <chr> "4 Stair Ascend Functional Test...
#> $ `CDISC Definition`             <chr> "4 Stair Ascend test code.", "4...
#> $ `NCI Preferred Term`           <chr> "CDISC Functional Test 4 Stair ...
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks :)

Comment: I noted that when in you install `rio` package, it also installs `openxlsx`, which apparently it uses to open xls from URL. Hence I upvoted the answer with openxlsx not with rio. It seems also much faster with openxls!

Comment: fair enough @IVIM I agree with that criterion. `rio`, as a wrapper, is my last resource when I can not read sth. If I need performance, better to use a more specific one. thanks for sharing!