# read_excel correctly imports file, but "invalid multibyte string" error when trying to put it on a list

Tags: r, readxl

When I read any of the sheets from the file [Posti-Letto-Istat.xls](https://github.com/maxtoki/misc/blob/master/Posti-Letto-Istat.xls) with `read_excel` from the `readxl` package I have no problems:

```
library(readxl)
pl_istat1 <- read_excel(path = "data/Posti-Letto-Istat.xls", sheet = 1, range = "A6:I66", na = "....")
```

However if I try to use a `lapply` or a `for` cycle to have all three sheets in a list, I get the following error.

```
lapply(1:3, function(i) read_excel(path = "data/Posti-Letto-Istat.xls", sheet = i, range = "A6:I66", na = "....")) 

Error in nchar(x, type = "width") : invalid multibyte string, element 4
```

I see that it's an encoding issue, and if I do something like

```
names(pl_istat[[i]]) <- iconv(enc2utf8(names(pl_istat[[i]])),sub="byte")
```

to each sheet, then I got no issue.

However, is there a way to have the list accept the `tibble` that gets correctly imported by `readxl`?

My Session Info:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          

[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         tools_3.3.3      bindrcpp_0.2     glue_1.1.1       dplyr_0.7.3      tibble_1.3.4     Rcpp_0.12.12    

[10] cellranger_1.1.0 rematch_1.0.1    pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.2      bindr_0.1
```

Comment: side question: any suggestion on where to store an Excel file for the reproducible example so that the actual path can be directly typed in R?

Comment: Your code ran just fine for me using the file you linked. I'm using R 3.4.1 and a Mac, so it's possible that this is a version or system problem. As for directly typing the path, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package) post may be what you're looking for, but I'm not sure if it's really any more reproducible that way.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I haven't had a chance to install the newer version. I'll report back on whether that solves it on Windows too.

Comment: I just updated to R 3.4.2 and I'm getting the same error.
So it's not the version, maybe the system?

Comment: I am working with 3.5.1 beta and the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error and could solve it by wrapping `read_excel()` with `as.data.frame()`

```
lapply(
  1:3, 
  function(i) {
    as.data.frame(
      read_excel(path = "data/Posti-Letto-Istat.xls", sheet = i, range = "A6:I66", na = "....")
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: I hadn't looked into this in a long time, sorry. I'm going to accept this one. Hopefully better late than never.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to save tibbles created using `readxl` into a list. 
Since I had multiple header rows I read only the headers first, concatenated them and created a vector named `headers` with the column names. Then read the actual data with `read_excel` and with the parameter `col_names = FALSE`. I had no problem saving these "nameless" tibbles into a list, but if I renamed the columns using `headers` I'd get this error:

```
Error in nchar(x[is_na], type = "width") : 
  invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

I solved it by issue by changing the encoding before renaming the tibble:

```
headers <- enc2native(headers)
```

But after this, when the list is printed I get this warning:

```
In fansi::strwrap_ctl(x, width = max(width, 0), indent = indent,  :
  Encountered a C0 control character, see `?unhandled_ctl`; you can use `warn=FALSE` to turn off these warnings.
```

which appears to be caused by a bug in base R according to [1](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/223) and [2](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/574), and it hasn't been an issue for me.