# read.xlsx Error in loadWorkbook(file, password = password) : Cannot find

Tags: r, file, gdata, install.packages, r-xlsx

I am trying to open the .xls file from this link 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/datasets/regionalgvaibylocalauthorityintheuk/1997to2015/regionalgvaibylainuk.xls' with the package 'xlsx', but it does not seem to be working. I have tried other packages like 'gdata' unsuccessfully, too.

```
install.packages('xlsx')
require('xlsx')

file <- system.file('https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/datasets/regionalgvaibylocalauthorityintheuk/1997to2015/regionalgvaibylainuk.xls', package = "xlsx")
res <- read.xlsx(file, 5) # read the fifth sheet
```

I get this error:
'Error in loadWorkbook(file, password = password) : Cannot find'

I have also tried the function read.xls(), but it throws me an error, too.

Comment: `system.file` is used to find a file within a package, but you are trying to read a file which is on a website, not it the xlsx package. Try downloading the file, and then reading it.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be reproducible by other people, so I have to rely on something which everyone could have access to.

Comment: Even if I try pasting the link on the read.xlsx function, I get this error: Error in read.xlsx("https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/datasets/regionalgvaibylocalauthorityintheuk/1997to2015/regionalgvaibylainuk.xls",  : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer from [Read Excel file from a URL using the readxl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package) can be used here:

```
library(httr)
library(xlsx)

url1<-'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/datasets/regionalgvaibylocalauthorityintheuk/1997to2015/regionalgvaibylainuk.xls'
GET(url1, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
res <- read.xlsx(tf, 5)
```

Comment: Would you know how to set the first non-NA rows as your column names?

Comment: I would say the easiest way is to use the `startRow` argument when you are reading the file, so the line would be `res <- read.xlsx(tf, 5, startRow = 3)`.  This will have the structure of the data.frame determined based on the actual data.