# How do I read excel file through URL in R studio? Its https

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I have a secure Url which provides data in Excel format. How do I read it in R studio?

Please mention the necessary package and functions. I have tried `read.xls()`,
`read_xlsx`, `read.URL` and some more. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368947/10447055 does this help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Excel file from a URL using the readxl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps. First, you'll need to download it with something like `download.file`, then read it with `readxl::read_excel`

```
download.file("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls", destfile = "/tmp/file.xls")
readxl::read_excel("/tmp/file.xls")
```

Comment: Tried this. It does not work. Any other way? It throws this https://www.screencast.com/t/vjaCRwNmi7

Comment: @Samprita it appears your error is indicating you have specified a file extension xlsx instead of xls. This may be the issue. Alternatively, your firewall may block the connection which is an issue with this type of question.

Comment: You can try saving to another location, preferably in your home directory where you certainly will have read/write permissions

Answer (score -1):

```
library(readxl)
library(httr)

url<-'https://......xls'
GET(url, write_disk(TF <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
read_excel(TF)
```

Comment: Please add some detailed and meaningful explanation into your answer

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried importing it as a .csv dataset into RStudio? Might be worth a try!:)