# How to upload xls files from url address into R Studio?

Tags: r, url, download

No problem trying to upload a csv file:

```
url <- read.csv("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.csv")
```

When trying to upload the same file, but xls:

```
urn <- read_xls("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.xls")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.xls’
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Excel file from a URL using the readxl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368628/read-excel-file-from-a-url-using-the-readxl-package)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. This will help.

```
install.packages("rio")
data <- rio::import("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.xls")
head(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help AR Ashiq. Actually I finally used the following code:  install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
urlgdp<-'http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.xls'
pgdp<-tempfile()
download.file(urlgdp,pgdp,mode="wb")
dbgdp<-read_excel(path=pgdp,sheet=1)